Why is the union of all dyadic cubes Q that are fully contained in an open ball equal to the open ball itself?
Tao proves Lemma 1.2.11 in his introduction to measure theory, and I’m confused by one part.
He defines a closed dyadic cube $ Q $ in  $\mathbb{R}^d $ as:
$$Q = \left[\frac{i_1}{2^n}, \frac{i_1+1}{2^n}\right] \times \cdots \times \left[\frac{i_d}{2^n}, \frac{i_d+1}{2^n}\right]$$
He proves that any two closed dyadic cubes are either almost disjoint or one is contained in the other, which makes sense to me.
But then he claims that the union of all dyadic cubes fully contained in an open ball  E  equals to E itself.
I don’t understand why this is true.
Closed dyadic cubes are closed sets, so why does their union equal an open set?
Following is a part of the original proof.



I would advise drawing 2-3 pictures of the same $E$=circle and covered by the mesh. From picture to picture, the mesh should get finer. This helps with the intuition, I find.

Thank you for your advice!


Closed dyadic cubes are closed sets, so why does their union equal an
open set?

This is a topological question. Infinite union of closed sets can result in an open set. For a simpler example, consider
$$(a,b) = \bigcup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}  \left[a+\frac{1}{n}, b -\frac{1}{n} \right]$$
Similarly, infinite intersections of open sets can result in closed sets.

But then he claims that the union of all dyadic cubes fully contained
in an open ball E equals to E itself.

Consider any point $p$ at $E$. Then you can find a "dyadic radius" $1/2^n$ small enough so that it is contained in a ball around $p$ which is itself contained in $E$ (exists by openness).

I don’t understand why this is true.

Maybe you are confused by the fact that in the union, we first take large dyadic cubes and then we take smaller ones and the smaller ones? Indeed, the large ones that we take in the beginning are useless, it is all about filling in (in the limit) the empty space not covered by the large cubes.

To expand a bit on @qarabala's answer: suppose $E$ is the open ball of radius $t$ around $b$ for some $t > 0$, and $A$ is the union of all dyadic cubes contained in $E$. It's clear that $A \subseteq E$, so we need only show that $E \subseteq A$. So suppose that $x \in E$: we want to show that $x \in A$.
As Tai points out, since $E$ is open, there is an open ball $B(x, \epsilon) \subseteq E$ for some $\epsilon > 0$ (in fact $\epsilon = t - \rho(b, x)$ will work). Now we just need to find a dyadic cube containing $x$ which is inside $B(x, \epsilon)$. This is not hard because, intuitively, dyadic cubes are everywhere and they are as small as you like.
Consider a cube (not necessarily dyadic) of the form $C_u = \Pi_i [x_i - u, x_i + u]$ for some $u$. For $c \in C_u$, the distance from $x$ to $c$ is $\sqrt{\Sigma (x_i - c_i)^2} \le \sqrt{du^2} = u \sqrt{d}$. So choose $u > 0$ with $u \sqrt{d} < \epsilon$, and then we have $C_u \subseteq B(x, \epsilon)$.
Finally we want to find a still-smaller cube inside $C_u$ which is dyadic. Find $n$ such that $1/2^n < u$. Then for each $i$, the interval $[x_i - u, x_i + u]$ has length $2u$, and therefore must contain some dyadic interval $[p_i/2^n, (p_i + 1)/2^n]$. So the dyadic cube $\Pi_i [p_i/2^n, (p_i + 1)/2^n]$ lies inside $C_u$, and therefore inside $B(x, \epsilon)$, and therefore inside $E$, as required.
